# Swiper JS infinite carousel shift

Tags: jquery, slider, swiper.js, autoplay

I wanted to make an endless carousel with swiper js on my site and it works, but when you look carefully, there is a small vibration between the slides, it seems like the image is flickering, and I couldn't find a solution for this, I would like to say that I am very happy in advance if you can help :) I want it to move smoothly.

[swiper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVc48.png)

HTML

```
          <div class="partners-main-body">
        <div class="swiper default-partners">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="partners-slider-item">
                <img src="dist/img/logo-axa.jpg" alt="Axa" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="partners-slider-item">
                <img src="dist/img/logo-axa.jpg" alt="Axa" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="partners-slider-item">
                <img src="dist/img/logo-axa.jpg" alt="Axa" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="partners-slider-item">
                <img src="dist/img/logo-axa.jpg" alt="Axa" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="partners-slider-item">
                <img src="dist/img/logo-axa.jpg" alt="Axa" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="partners-slider-item">
                <img src="dist/img/logo-axa.jpg" alt="Axa" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Swiper JS Settings:

```
  var defpartners = new Swiper('.default-partners', {
loop: true,
speed: 2500,
grabCursor: true,
centeredSlides: true,

autoplay: {
  delay: 0,
  disableOnInteraction: false,
},
breakpoints: {
  320: {
    slidesPerView: 1.5,
    spaceBetween: 16,
  },
  545: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 16,
  },
  991: {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 16,
  },
  1124: {
    slidesPerView: 4.2,

    spaceBetween: 30,
  },
},
```

})

Answer (score 0):

```
breakpoints: {
320: {
slidesPerView: 1,
spaceBetween: 16,
},
545: {
slidesPerView: 2,
spaceBetween: 16,
},
991: {
slidesPerView: 3,
spaceBetween: 16,
},
1124: {
slidesPerView: 4,

spaceBetween: 30,
},
},
```